# Create dynamic horizontal listview of items and select the first item by default in flutter

Tags: flutter, horizontallistview

I want to create a horizontal list of elements in flutter. It will be like horizontal button type containers(not buttons) and I want the first item in the list to be selected when the page loads. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply declare a variable which will hold list and the selectedIndex and then use this selected index to highlight the item selected:-

```
int selectedIndex=0;//will highlight first item
List<String> youList=['1,'2','3','4'];//suppose this is your dynamic list
```

Now code for the horizontal listview:-

```
SizedBox(
height: 100,
child: ListView.builder(
    shrinkWrap:  true,
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    itemCount: yourList.length,
    itemBuilder: (context,index){
      return Container(
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        color: selectedIndex==index?Colors.green:Colors.red,//now suppose selectedIndex and index from this builder is same then it will show the selected as green and others in red color
        child: ,//here you can show the child or data from the list
      );
    },
  )
),
```

Above example shows highlighting the box if selected but you can modify as per your need like you want to show border for highlight or anything else..